# Creating a new package in Java to make Web Service requests, what should I call it?

Tags: java, naming, conventions

Bit of a newbie question, but I'm unfamiliar with Java.  I'm thinking either:

`com.company.webservices`

or

`com.company.webserviceretriever`

or

`com.company.webservice.retriever`

Any thoughts or opinions on the matter?

Comment: Any of those look fine -- the first or the third are both clearer than the second.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such hard and fast rule. But `com.company.service` should have the interface and `com.company.service.impl` in which you implement the interface which internally consumes the web service. In future if you want to change the implementation from web service to something else it will still make sense and your service client should have no idea about it.